# Unable to display Google map in application (inflating class fragment - exception)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-fragments

I am trying to display a simple Google map in my app. I am following this tutorial    http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html but I get an exception -  inflating class fragment. So I have the following XML code.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".DrawMap" >

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

The java file:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class DrawMap extends Activity  
{
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw_map);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}


}
```

I dont understand what am I doing wrong. I am following the tutorial step by step and 
I still get the inflating class fragment exception.

the manifest.xml file code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="musat.modum.mobilephone.application"
android:versionCode="8"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"
    tools:ignore="OldTargetApi" />
<permission android:name="com.example.testmapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >           

    <activity
        android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.DrawMap"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_draw_map" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDtZreW9OZf2aIe4NKj3SJRGqBrkjHQ9E8" />
</application>
```

Comment: let me see your manifest.xml file and also logcat

Comment: oh right forgot about that let me edit my question

Comment: better to post your logcat